# Unable to Install Ionic on Windows

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I'm meant to be maintaining an Ionic app, but I cannot install Ionic on any of my machines (neither at work - Win 7) nor at home (Win 10).

Perhaps we could start with my home machine (Win 10). After the fail, I uninstalled Node completely, and restarted the machine. I re-installed Nodejs and upgraded npm such that the versions are:
Nodejs: 10.4.1
NPM: 6.1.0

The output from my Powershell prompt (at elevated privileges) is:

> PS F:\Code\Powershell\Toolkit> npm install -g ionic
>   npm ERR! path C:\Users\roger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules.readable-stream.DELETE
>   npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
>   npm ERR! errno -4051
>   npm ERR! syscall rmdir
>   npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\roger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules.readable-stream.DELETE'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\roger\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-17T01_32_39_358Z-debug.log

Interestingly, the directory `.readable-stream.DELETE` referred to as being not empty, is empty. So, not sure what is going on there.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: use node -v 8 npm for nodejs version 10 is yet not supported

Comment: I uninstalled 10, installed v8.11.3 I'm getting the same error. Even after a restart.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444 check this thread

Comment: Whenever you trouble with the file system (directory not getting emptied quickly enough in this case), be sure to disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: I cannot, for the life of me, delete the `.readable-stream.DELETE` directory. That seems to be the problem. I've tried all sorts of flags like -recurse -force and even tried to shorten the path using the good old subst comment. It will not be deleted.

Comment: This may take a while. I'm now in a Safe Mode loop of death. I booted into safe mode, but I cannot type my password as the screen freezes. Any reboot goes straight back to the same frozen login screen. Need to get my hands on a DVD to repair Windows. I really hope Ionic is worthwhile. Heck! Why does it need a directory named `.readable-stream.DELETE` anyway. There's a bit of free feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is sort out that directory deletion issue. Make sure you uninstall Nodejs to make sure none of its processes are locking that directory.

Try the following.

1. Right-click the drive upon which that directory is located (probably C drive).
2. Click Properties on the Context Menu
3. Go to the Tools tab
4. Click the `Check` button.

Let it run its course. Once complete, if all looks well, try deleting the directory again.

If that succeeded, install Node again (v8.11.3). Don't upgrade NPM.
Install Ionic again with `npm install -g ionic`
Create an app `ionic start myApp tabs`
Change to the myApp directory.
Run `ionic serve`

Hopefully the first part will clear away that folder and get you on your way.

Comment: Finally! Thanks David.